# How to Use AdMob Pro plugin with Framework7?

Tags: cordova, admob, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am new on framework7. I have successfully created an android app with framework7 and I am glad with it.
But the problem was created when I added admob pro plugin in this project.
After added it, shown a message in alert “admob plugin not ready”

therefore I have already used window.cordova.plugins.AdMob; ,window.AdMob;,
window.plugins.AdMob; and window.plugins, but problem still here.

But when I remove Framework7 files and run project on my device, so admob plugin working perfectly and show me test ad.
But when I add Framework7 files and run project on my device, so admob plugin not working and show me the message again on alert “admob plugin not ready”.

If someone have the solution of this problem so kindly reply.